# Do we need to call `load` before reading `ooxml` of an API object?

Tags: ms-word, eslint, office-js

The following code produces an error in linting, while still working correctly:

```
function getSelectionOoxml(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    return Word.run(async (context) => {
      const ooxml = context.document.getSelection().getOoxml()
      await context.sync()
      resolve(ooxml.value)
    })
  })
}
```

The error message is:

> An explicit load call on 'ooxml' for property 'value' needs to be made before the property can be read

Violated rule in this case is `office-addins/load-object-before-read`. Do we really need to call `load` before reading ooxml? If yes, what do I provide as argument? I tried `value` as suggested, but that doesn't work and instead produces another error saying that there is no `value` property in this object.

Comment: I think it is a mistake in the linter. `getOoxml` returns an `OfficeExtension.ClientResult` object. I don't think that explicit loading applies to objects in the `OfficeExtension` namespace.

Comment: @RickKirkham: That's my conclusion too. Thanks for the input.